# Material UI React Form submission sometimes doesn't record email input properly

Tags: forms, next.js, react-hooks, material-ui

I have a next.js site that displays a webpage with a single-field form requesting people to signup with their email. When they signup we record their email. Sometimes the email shows up as empty even though there is form validation built in. Every now and then there are also multiple form submissions around the same time.

This is frustrating to debug because i) I have been unable to reproduce it on localhost, ii) it sometimes works, iii) the problem is on the client side.

I keep thinking there is some race condition happening but not sure.

The full code is reproduced below:

`

```
const Form = props => {
  const { className, ...rest } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = useState("");
  const emailRef = useRef();

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setState("submitting");
    const dispatch = {email: emailRef.current.value, url: window.location.href}
    console.log("Invoking the api/emailsidebar with:")
    console.log(dispatch)
    const res = await axios.post("/api/emailsidebar", dispatch);
    setState(res.status == 200 ? "success" : "error");   
    setTimeout(() => setState(""), 3000);
  };
  
  const renderMessage = () => {
    if (state === "submitting") 
      return (
        <>Submitting...</>
      )
    if (state === "error")
      return (
        <>There has been an error. Please try again.</>
      );
    if (state === "success")
      return (
        <>You are all set. Thank you for signing up to our mailing list!</>
      )
    return (
        <>Submit your email here.</>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
     <form className={classes.inputContainer} onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <FormControl
          fullWidth
          variant="outlined"
          data-aos="fade-up"
          className={classes.formControl}
        >
          <div className={classes.form}>
            <Grid container spacing={isMd ? 4 : 2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} data-aos="fade-up">
                          <TextField
                            placeholder="Your e-mail address"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="medium"
                            name="email"
                            inputRef={emailRef} 
                            fullWidth
                            type="email"
                            // value={values.email}
                          />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item container justify="center" xs={12}>
                            <Button
                              variant="contained"
                              type="submit"
                              color="secondary"
                              size="large"
                            >
                              Subscribe
                            </Button>
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item container justify="center" xs={12}>
                        <Typography variant="caption" color="textSecondary">
                            {renderMessage()}
                        </Typography>
                      </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </div>
        </FormControl>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

`
```

Any help/suggestions would be useful.

This works well on localhost - never fails. But after deployment it many times records an empty email. It does work sometimes.